# Java Casting Difference Array to Variable

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

i was studying OCA exam and something drown my attraction. If I make a casting like that

```
Object[] arr = new Object[] { 10, "OZAN", 15.0, 12.5f };
String s = (String) arr[1];
```

everything will be fine.
But if I try that piece of code

```
Object o = new Object();
Integer i = (Integer) o;
```

it will throw an **ClassCastException**. The misunderstanding point is, both of two I 
have made casting operation but only one thrown **ClassCastException**. What is the reason of that situation ? Thank you all.

Comment: i'd suggest some brushing up on casting fundamentals, downcast/upcast. it's the principles of inheritance and polymorphism. your answer will become clear understanding that Object sits at the highest level in the inheritance hierarchy for java.

Comment: Bu arada önce ki sorularını inceledim verilen cevaplar doğru olmasına rağmen onaylamamıssın, sol tarafta ki sayının altında ki tike tıklayarak onaylayabilirsin.

Comment: In the first case, you're casting an `Object` reference, which points to a `String`, to a `String`. It is a `String`, so this is fine. In the second case, you're casting a `Object` reference, which points to an `Object`, to an `Integer`. It is not an `Integer`, so this fails.

Comment: @AndyTurner < Actually, he should learn what polymorphism is and how it works, sir.

Comment: @snr yes, that sounds like a good idea. But why are you actually telling me?

Comment: @AndyTurner < There is a proverb in Turkish that _"kızım sana söylüyorum, gelinim sen anla"_ means that _since he(me in this case) doesn't say this directly to him(OP), he(me) said it to someone else(you) in the hope that he(OP) would listen in and get the message_

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in what the object truly is.

If you did `Object o = new Integer(5);` as an example, it will not throw a `ClassCastExecption`. This is because o is not an integer, it is an object while `arr[1]` is a string. It is also an object, but it is a string as well, which allows it to be cast.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the API Specifications for the [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance.

You can use  `instanceof` keyword which is a *binary operator* used to test if an *object* (instance) is a subtype of a given `Type`.

Let's examplify,

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new Object();
        Object i = 5; // auto-boxing
        Object[] arr = new Object[] { 10, "Acar çalış ozan", 15.0, 12.5f };

        if (arr[1] instanceof String)
            System.out.println("arr[1] is an instance of String");
        if (i instanceof Integer)
            System.out.println("i is an instance of Integer");
        if (o instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("o is an instance of Integer");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("o is NOT an instance of Integer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to seperate 2 differents things :

- the type of the reference
- the type of the object refered by the reference

`arr[1]` reference type is `Object` and it refers to the object `"OZAN"` of type `String` so your cast `(String) arr[1]` is allowed

`o` reference type is `Object` and it refers to the object `new Object()` of type `Object`

So the instruction `(Integer) o` try to convert an object of type `Object` to a type `Integer` which is called a downcast (casting to a subtype).
Downcast is simply not allowed in Java and generates a ClassCastExecption at runtime